# Unexpected CS0266 cast error, why is the extra cast required?

Tags: c#, generics

**Background**
I encounter an generics error and can easily fix it by adding a cast.
But why do I have to add the `(IIndexTableDefs)` as the returned value is already the type asked for?

```
public class IndexTableDefinitionsController : ParameterDefinitionsBaseController<IIndexTableDef>
{
    internal override IIndexTableDefs GetDefinitions<IIndexTableDefs>()
        => Core.StaticDefinitions.Instance.IndexTableDefs;
}
```

reports an error :

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'SNG.LccNion.Intf.IIndexTableDefs' to 'IIndexTableDefs'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) SNG.LccNion.API S:\Sources\LCCNion\Source\SNG.LccNion.API\Controllers\Definitions\IndexTableDefinitionsController.cs    17  Active
```

when I add the cast like so:

```
public class IndexTableDefinitionsController : ParameterDefinitionsBaseController<IIndexTableDef>
{
    internal override IIndexTableDefs GetDefinitions<IIndexTableDefs>()
        => (IIndexTableDefs) Core.StaticDefinitions.Instance.IndexTableDefs;
}
```

the error message goes away. I fail to understand *why* the error appears as the requested `IndexTableDefs` property is already of type `IIndexTableDefs` (from the same name space, there is no other `IIndexTableDefs` in my sources)

```
public interface IStaticDefinitions
{
    ....
    public IIndexTableDefs IndexTableDefs { get; }       
    ....
}
```

the abstract base routine looks like this:

```
public abstract class DefinitionBaseController<IItemType> : LccNionBaseController
    where IItemType : class, IGenericIDDescriptive<IItemType>, IIDDescriptive
{
    .....
    internal abstract ICollectionType GetDefinitions<ICollectionType>()
        where ICollectionType:IGenericIDDescriptives<IItemType>;
    .....
}
```

**Q:** - a (hopefully simple) explanation why this happens, could it be a compiler issue?

(Using VS2022)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've just defined a generic method, `IIndexTableDefs` in the scope is a generic type parameter, not the interface.

```
IIndexTableDefs GetDefinitions<IIndexTableDefs>()
```

is equivalent to

```
T GetDefinitions<T>()
```

Comment: I already thought something like this looking at the error message, where 1 shows the full namespace and the other none. I have not yet found a way around this (except for the cast off course) - thx

Comment: The workaround I found was to add the collection type as type specifier to the base class as well. This quite simplified the underlying code in other spots with far less generics and casts